# How to wrap div fields and maintaing equal width while using @media screen

Tags: css

Anyone know how to wrap div's using @media screen and maintain equal width on all div's. I have tried using float and inline-block but can’t find a way to keep all field widths equally justified. Using table-cells provides the means to maintain equal field width but does not permit row/cell changes on @media screen. I have provided an example using table cells just to show what I’m trying to achieve. Note: I'm also trying to avoid fixed field width.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6jj6qx8a/

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">
.celln {
 display:table-cell;
 padding-right:10px;
 background:#dddddd;
}
.cellv {
 display:table-cell;
 padding-right:10px;
 background:#00ff00;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 400px ) {
}
</style>

From this...<br><br>

<div style="display:table;">
 <div style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="celln">Name:</div>
  <div class="cellv">John Johnson</div>

  <div class="celln">Employer:</div>
  <div class="cellv">ABC Company</div>
 </div>
 <div style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="celln">Address:</div>
  <div class="cellv">123 State St NW</div>

  <div class="celln">Zip Code:</div>
  <div class="cellv">12345</div>
 </div>
</div>

<br><br>to this on @media screen and ( max-width: 400px ) <br><br>

<div style="display:table;">
 <div style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="celln">Name:</div>
  <div class="cellv">John Johnson</div>
 </div>
 <div style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="celln">Employer:</div>
  <div class="cellv">ABC Company</div>
 </div>
 <div style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="celln">Address:</div>
  <div class="cellv">123 State St NW</div>
 </div>
 <div style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="celln">Zip Code:</div>
  <div class="cellv">12345</div>
 </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a div containing both tables.

Set table width to 100% and set the parent div a % with too.

Comment: Using a % will make my width fixed on that % instead of using the content to calculate overall minimum width needed for the entire table.

Comment: and you tryed using flexbox?